# Ui Automation - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out for "driver url"

Tags: karate

My web page is very slow and taking approx 1 minute to load page. Hence causing below line to fail.

```
* configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', executable: '/Users/vikas/Apps/chromedriver', showDriverLog: true }
* driver 'http://XXXX.XXX'
```

I configured readTimeout in **karate-config.js** but no help:

> karate.configure('readTimeout', 60000);

**Error Message**:

```
ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, http call failed after 30003 milliseconds for URL: http://localhost:9515/session/c7c09b611f294b8d13ef7d63668b2677/url
ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed: 
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

For Selenium WebDriver there is infinite timeout for driver.get(url) which can be changed by pageLoadTimeout() .

Is there anything with Karate Core to handle such long page loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the config for the HTTP client used for the UI driver is separate. So you do something like this:

```
* configure driver = { httpConfig: { readTimeout: 120000 } }
```

Just add `httpConfig` to your existing driver configuration.

Refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#configure-driver